# Is it possible to change disk in RAID0 array of Intel Rapid Storage Tehnology?

Tags: raid, intel, replace, raid0, rst

My BIOS started to report red line with error for one of 2 drives in RAID0 array during boot.
But file system appears to be working without any visible problems, so I was able to make system image and necessary backups.

I want to purchase same size drive and replace one of drives of my RAID0 without losing information and without restoring from system image.

Is it possible and how ?

Is it possible to convert my array to RAID5 by adding third drive and then replace suspicious drive ?

I know that RAID0 does not provide fault tolerance, but my drive still works and holds the information, so there is not fault yet, which of course would not be recoverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup and restore is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this Intel stuff but you could try this: Copy the whole content of the disk to be replaced to the new disk using dd (don't forget `noerror`). If your RAID solution does not store serial numbers and the like then there is a chance that the RAID continues working after changing the disks. I would expect this to work with software RAID.